# Why am I not getting any index defintions in my Rails schema.db - "# unrecognized index ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5, Postgres backend, with some read-only access to an external Oracle database.

My schema.db file is not getting any index definitions. Instead, I am getting lines in schema.db that say:

```
# unrecognized index "auditable_index" with type ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::IndexDefinition
```

Comment: What gem are you using for postgres connectivity?

Comment: I son't see a "postgres" gem when I do "gem list" or "gem list --local".  Does that mean there is a default gem?  In my database.yml, it uses the adapter 'postgresql.'

Comment: Does your rails application connect to both Postgres and Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 2.3.5 does not fully support Oracle out of the box.  Using the sql schema format instead of schema.rb should work around the issue.

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

I think the oracle-enhanced gem supports the proper generation of Oracle indexes but I've never used it.  Might be worth a shot if you don't want to change your schema format.

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced

Comment: Is this true even when all the add_index calls are on tables in my local postgres database?  I was guessing it might be oracle-related, because when I googled the error message, the few mentions I saw were for Oracle, but since I'm not actually changing the Oracle database at all (not adding indexes or data) it seemed odd that an Oracle restriction would be the problem...

Comment: Keep in mind that migration files (where add_index would be called) are not used when building the schema.rb file.  When  ActiveRecord generates a schema.rb file (when schema_format = :ruby) it asks the connection adapter to query the database for schema objects.  You can see the code for Postgresql [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.5/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L622).  My assumption is that your Postgresql indexes would be built correctly and your Oracle not but I'm not sure.  Either way using schema_format = :sql solves everything.